# Renaming a drectory in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

i am just trying to rename a android text directory name and i have really having a tough time and nothing seems to solve my problem . have a look below to see the screenshot of my directory.

**[SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrwZG.jpg)**

now you will see a  folder with the following name

```
com.example.gautam.droidone
```

what i would really like to do is rename the file to the following:

```
com.example.gautam.droidone.tests
```

i was going through this tutorial and also the android official tutorial and they require that your test directory have a suffix of `tests`.

now waht i did to change the name is pretty standard.

right click on the folder > select refactor > rename > in the popup that appears enter the name, i entered droidone.tests.

my folder gets renamed to the following instead:

```
com.example.gautam.tests
```

what i want is really:

```
com.example.gautam.droidone.tests
```

so how do i rename my file , can somebody address this simple issue that i am facing ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You have to rename the package and also the directory .. You should be able to see rename directory under redactor menu option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`com.example.gautam.droidone` is not a directory name - it's a package name, which is represented by a set of folders in the file system: `com/example/gautam/droidone`. Android Studio for your convenience flattens these folders into a package name.

To add `tests` folder to this path you can, for example, call `New package` while being in `droidone` folder, and then move your classes to this new package.

Comment: so you suggest instead of renaming `com.example.gautam.droidone` to `com.example.gautam.droidone.tests` i should add a folder under `com.example.gautam.droidone` called tests and then move the test files inside that ?